# Tflite Kotlin outputFeature0AsTensorBuffer.floatArray give so many values

Tags: kotlin, android-studio, tflite

Im newbie, i have tflite model for android app. When i use this code -> val outputFeature0 = outputs.outputFeature0AsTensorBuffer.floatArray i got so many values. But i have only 220 classes in my tflite model. What should i do now for normalize output.

```
val model = TonsFp16.newInstance(context)

// Creates inputs for reference.
val inputFeature0 = TensorBuffer.createFixedSize(intArrayOf(1, 224, 224, 3), DataType.FLOAT32)
inputFeature0.loadBuffer(byteBuffer)

// Runs model inference and gets result.
val outputs = model.process(inputFeature0)
val outputFeature0 = outputs.outputFeature0AsTensorBuffer

// Releases model resources if no longer used.
model.close()
```

I want a 220 values from output.